# Extracting sql from SSRS Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to extract the sql from all my SSRS reports so I can see what database tables and columsn are used . Does anyone know how to do this if you have 50 reports ? Is there any exsiting functionality I have overlooked that does this ?

Comment: If you are trying to programmatically extract all the queries, the answer is that there isn't any functionality like that. If you mean extract the query from the .rdl files without opening Visual Studio, you can just open all the files with a text editor.

Comment: Just found this. http://bretstateham.com/extracting-ssrs-content-using-the-ssis-%E2%80%9Cexport-column%E2%80%9D-component/

Comment: Are all SSRS reports listed in ReportServer database in 2008 & 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDL files are simple XML files. You could create a simple parser that extracts the information you want. If you don't have access to the RDL files right now, you can download them through the SSRS web interface.

Here's an excerpt of the relevant part of an RDL file:

```
<DataSets>
<DataSet Name="Test">
  <Fields>
    <Field Name="Testfield">
      <DataField>Testfield</DataField>
      <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
    </Field>
  </Fields>
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>MyDataSource</DataSourceName>
    <CommandType>StoredProcedure</CommandType>
    <CommandText>spMyGreatStoredProcedure</CommandText>
    <QueryParameters>
      <QueryParameter Name="@param1">
        <Value>=Parameters!Param1.Value</Value>
      </QueryParameter>
      <QueryParameter Name="@param2">
        <Value>=Parameters!Param2.Value</Value>
      </QueryParameter>
    <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
  </Query>
</DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

There are one or more `DataSet` blocks, which define one data set of the report. First, all the fields are defined and then the query with its parameters.